# Installing SASS on Yosemite

Tags: macos, sass, rubygems

I'm struggling with an error in my command line while trying to install SASS.

I'm just following what SASS website recommend to type in the command line:

```
sudo gem install sass
```

and here is the error I got:

```
    My-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ gem install sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: sass
```

Then when I try to test if it installed with command line:

```
sass -v
```

I got:

```
-bash: sass: command not found
```

I have a 2015 macbook pro with the latest OSX Yosemite.

Alternatively, how could I install SASS manually? I see it trying to download  https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score -1):

That's probably because the servers serving gems are blocked in China (for whatever reason that is). An easier way to solve this would be:

1. Open a terminal
2. `gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/`
3. `gem sources -a https://ruby.taobao.org/` (this is a mirror of rubygems.org)
4. `gem update --system`
5. `sudo gem install sass`

Done. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Damonh, I'll try that later but at the moment I'm using Scout App for mac which does the jod pretty well and relatively fast.

Comment: % gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    Could not find a valid gem 'rubygems-update' (2.6.6) locally or in a repository